# How to use AWSmanaged Role in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to attach an AWS managed Role to my EC2 instance in CloudFormation. Here for I need to attach the managed role to an instance profile and attach the instance profile to the EC2.

How can I attach the managed role to the instance profile?
I tried:

```
  ASGIAMInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      InstanceProfileName: asg-instance-profile
      Roles:
        - AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
```

But I got:

```
Cannot perform the operation on the protected role 'AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling' - this role is only modifiable by AWS (Service:
```

I know I can recreate a comparable role and attach it to an instance profile but that seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "managed roles" are [service-linked roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html). These are special roles that are directly attached to a service itself and cannot be attached to other entities.

You can, however, associate a [Managed Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html) with roles. These are the policies shown in the "Policies" section of the IAM management console.

Comment: So I still need to create a new Role but use the managed policy?

Comment: Yes. If you wish to add a Managed Policy to an EC2 instance, you will need to create a role, attach the policy to the role, then attach the role to the instance via an `InstanceProfile`.

Comment: Okay. I was just confused because the role AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling did already exist so I hoped I did not had to "recreate" it.